# MOSFET switch in 120 V AC application with Arduino Uno

Tags: mosfet, switching, arduino-uno

I am working on a project that requires an Arduino Uno to activate a safety mechanism using 120 V AC from a power supply.

1. Is the following diagram correct, and are there items (such as a buffer/driver) that are missing?
   [image: Circuit Diagram]
2. What do I need to know to select the correct MOSFET switch?
3. General advice to keep in mind.

Comment: No, a MOSFET won't work for AC and you'd be wise to add galvanic isolation between the 120V AC circuit and the low voltage Arduino. Consider a relay, for example.

Comment: Generally when interfacing a low-voltage digital circuit with mains you'll want isolation through an optoisolator or similar device.  The circuit you've posted won't work.  Do you have a datasheet for the safety device?

Comment: I can smell the smoke from here already ...

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of the risk this device will be protecting? If there is a risk of non-reversible injury (lost of life or amputation, etc.) then the design requirements change significantly.

Comment: There are ready-to-use modules with a **relay** that are easy to use with an Arduino and that will provide the **isolation** that is needed for **safety** reasons. Start reading here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-relay-module-with-arduino/ You **WILL** blow things up if you implement the schematic that you show. Also you **WILL** get sparks and electrical shocks as well. So just use the relay module.

Comment: I would think twice about using an Arduino UNO if the safety mechanism is to protect life and limb. There may be laws and requirements depending where you are in the world.

Comment: I mean no offence, but your level of electronics experience seems like a very bad match for working with mains electricity. The fact that this concerns a safety device makes it even more worrisome. Please consider outsourcing this to someone with the proper knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relay module instead: safe, isolated, works with AC.

https://www.google.com/search?client=q=Arduino+relay+module

https://www.amazon.com/Arduino-Relay-Module/s?k=Arduino+Relay+Module

[image: Typical relay module]

Comment: For beginners, this is the best choice for a cheap solution to switching AC loads. They are offered in many sizes up to 8 per board and double insulated with opto interfaces. But users should be aware of arc noise when switching off and use twisted pairs to loads.

Answer (score 0):

That does look terribly bad. You’re inputing 120 AC directly into Arduino, which means Arduino will blow up. Not sure if “Safety Mech” (what exactly is that?) will drop voltage and current, but otherwise 120 VAC doesn’t normally go into a MOSFET gate.

As others have said, just use a relay board. It usually has an optocoupler to separate mains AC from Arduino’s low voltage DC.

Answer (score 0):

All due respect , the 110 volts going direct into the Arduino ( twice,one straight connection and one via 10k resistor ) remember , the resistor limits current , but you might still have ( high current), it all seems a bit odd to be honestly generous . Also , on the load side it shows + 120 and - 120 vac  volts , I am not being mean but I would suggest “ neutral” and “ Hot”
Regards